# load specific visible people in google plus in android

Tags: android, google-plus

I have successfully implemented google plus

list people activity

```
public class ListPeopleActivity extends Activity implements
    PlusClient.ConnectionCallbacks, PlusClient.OnPeopleLoadedListener,
    PlusClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, DialogInterface.OnCancelListener {

private static final String TAG = "ListPeopleActivity";

private static final String STATE_RESOLVING_ERROR = "resolving_error";

private static final int DIALOG_GET_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = 1;

private static final int REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_GET_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = 2;

private ArrayAdapter mListAdapter;
private ListView mPersonListView;
private ArrayList<String> mListItems;
private PlusClient mPlusClient;
private boolean mResolvingError;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.person_list_activity);

    mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
            .setVisibleActivities(MomentUtil.VISIBLE_ACTIVITIES).build();

    mListItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    mListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mListItems);
    mPersonListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.person_list);
    mResolvingError = savedInstanceState != null
            && savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_RESOLVING_ERROR, false);

    int available = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (available != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        showDialog(DIALOG_GET_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES);
    }
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    if (id != DIALOG_GET_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES) {
        return super.onCreateDialog(id);
    }

    int available = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (available == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        return null;
    }
    if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(available)) {
        return GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(available, this,
                REQUEST_CODE_GET_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES, this);
    }
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage(R.string.plus_generic_error).setCancelable(true)
            .setOnCancelListener(this).create();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mPlusClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean(STATE_RESOLVING_ERROR, mResolvingError);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mPlusClient.disconnect();
}

@Override
public void onPeopleLoaded(ConnectionResult status,
        PersonBuffer personBuffer, String nextPageToken) {
    switch (status.getErrorCode()) {
    case ConnectionResult.SUCCESS:
        mListItems.clear();
        try {
            int count = personBuffer.getCount();
            Log.e("", "count : " + count);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                mListItems.add(personBuffer.get(i).getDisplayName());
                Log.e("", "" + personBuffer.get(i).getDisplayName() + " "
                        + personBuffer.get(i).getId() + " isPlusUser : "
                        + personBuffer.get(i).isPlusUser()
                        + " isVerified : "
                        + personBuffer.get(i).isVerified()
                        + " hasCircledByCount : "
                        + personBuffer.get(i).hasCircledByCount()
                        + " getObjectType : "
                        + personBuffer.get(i).getObjectType());
            }
        } finally {
            personBuffer.close();
        }

        mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        break;

    case ConnectionResult.SIGN_IN_REQUIRED:
        mPlusClient.disconnect();
        mPlusClient.connect();
        break;

    default:
        Log.e(TAG, "Error when listing people: " + status);
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN:
        mResolvingError = false;
        handleResult(resultCode);
        break;
    case REQUEST_CODE_GET_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES:
        handleResult(resultCode);
        break;
    }
}

private void handleResult(int resultCode) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // onActivityResult is called after onStart (but onStart is not
        // guaranteed to be called while signing in), so we should make
        // sure we're not already connecting before we call connect again.
        if (!mPlusClient.isConnecting() && !mPlusClient.isConnected()) {
            mPlusClient.connect();
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to sign the user in.");
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    mPersonListView.setAdapter(mListAdapter);
    // mPlusClient.loadVisiblePeople(this, null);
    mPlusClient.loadPeople(this, "103193341800315457743");

}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    mPersonListView.setAdapter(null);
    mPlusClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    if (mResolvingError) {
        return;
    }

    mPersonListView.setAdapter(null);
    try {
        result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN);
        mResolvingError = true;
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        // Get another pending intent to run.
        mPlusClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to sign the user in.");
    finish();
}
```

In above code it `mPlusClient.loadVisiblePeople(this, null);` load all visible(in circle) people.. I want to load one specific people which is in my circle. and `mPlusClient.loadPeople(this, "103193341800315457743");` this can load specific people but how can I know it is in my circle or not... because it returns everytime whether it is in my circle or not.

Actually I want to know that specific people is in my circle or not.

Answer (score 0):

try, **mPlusClient.loadPerson(this, "103193341800315457743");**