# Get Google Plus friends Android

Tags: android, google-plus

I am working with google + getting friends. I can successfully log in and get my credentials. But when I use mPlusClient.loadPeople(this, "me");, the return of

```
@Override
    public void onPeopleLoaded(ConnectionResult status, PersonBuffer personBuffer, String nextPageToken) {
        switch (status.getErrorCode()) {

        case ConnectionResult.SUCCESS:
            try {
                int count = personBuffer.getCount();
                Log.e("", "count : " + count);
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    Log.e("NAME", "" + personBuffer.get(i).getDisplayName());
                }
            } finally {
                personBuffer.close();
            }

            break;

        case ConnectionResult.SIGN_IN_REQUIRED:
            mPlusClient.disconnect();
            mPlusClient.connect();
            break;

        default:
            Log.e("TAG", "Error when listing people: " + status);
            break;
        }
    }
```

is only the details of the logged in user. Now what I what to achieve is to get the list of my friends. I tried using

```
mPlusClient.loadPeople(MainActivity.this, Person.Collection.Visible);
```

but it says "Collection cannot be resolved or is not a field".
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link somehow helped me to feftch the members of my circle in google plus.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271137/load-specific-visible-people-in-google-plus-in-android?rq=1)

```
mPlusClient.loadVisiblePeople(this, null);
```

solved the problem. People.Collection.VISIBLE is not already working. I do not know why.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're after the [PlusClient.loadVisiblePeople](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusClient.html#loadVisiblePeople%28com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient.OnPeopleLoadedListener,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

You can [see an example](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list#try-it) of the response using Web API explorer.