# How to fetch Friend List in Google Plus using GoogleApiClient?

Tags: android

```
I am newly in android and i am using GoogleApiClient for google plus login .there is login successfully but i am not get proper way to fetch Fiend List.
So please can any one help me.
```

**Use**

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'

**Here is link used for Login:-**

[Google Plus Login Link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating)

Thanks.

Comment: atleast google first https://www.google.co.in/search?q=google+plus+get+friends+list+android&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=uaE8VoWjIsmo0gSKzaKgCg

Comment: thanks,But i have done already but i did't get  Proper way to fetch friend using \n compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'

Comment: so you consider official document not to be "Proper way", https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Google Plus friends Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21326874/get-google-plus-friends-android)

Comment: GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient; there is no methode loadpeople

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you get the result using:

```
LoadPeopleResult
```

The above method should get you the list of friends.

Answer (score 0):

> use this
>
> ```
>  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
> ```
>
> and use interface

```
 ResultCallback<LoadPeopleResult>
```